# how to close modal when clicked outside of modal with javascript (multiple modal in one page)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In the site design that I am doing, several modals must be created on one page. I have created this mod. I want the modal to close whenever out of modal is clicked.
In the last part of the code `window.onclick = function(event){...}`, this code is effective only on the last modal (modal number 3) and is completely ineffective on other modals (modal number 1 and 2).
I don't know where there is a problem in the code that doesn't work completely.
Thank you for guiding me.

```js
const triggers = document.getElementsByClassName("trigger");
const triggerArray = Array.from(triggers).entries();
const modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
const closeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-close");

for (let [index, trigger] of triggerArray) {
  const toggleModal = () => {
    modals[index].classList.toggle("show-modal");
  };
  trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
  closeButtons[index].addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
  
  // window.onclick = function(event) {
  //     const isClickInside =                          modals[index].contains(event.target);
  //     if (!isClickInside) {
  //         modals[index].classList.toggle("show-modal");
  //     }
  // };

//  window.onclick = function(event) {
//      if (event.target === modals[index]) {
//          modals[index].classList.toggle("show-modal");
//      }
 // };
 
//I found it=> this is work
     window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      if(event.target === modals[index]){
        modals[index].classList.remove("show-modal");
        console.log(modals[index])
      }          
    });
}
```

```css
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s,           transform 0.25s;
}
  
.modal-content {
    align-self: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    width: 24rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
  
.btn-close {
    float: right;
    width: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
  
.show-modal {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s,             transform 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<button class="trigger">Modal 1</button>
<button class="trigger">Modal 2</button>
<button class="trigger">Modal 3</button>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="btn-close">&times;</span>
        <h1>modal 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="btn-close">&times;</span>
        <h1>modal 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="btn-close">&times;</span>
        <h1>modal 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element